# New files on Android shows 0 bytes in mounted folder

Tags: mount, android, sync

I have an Android device semi-permanently attached to a ubuntu computer.  The Android device is semi-permanently taking videos.

New video files show up about every 2 minutes in the mounted folder, but they show up as 0 bytes.

If I reboot the computer the file sizes show up correctly... but I'd like to sync the directory, and I'm not sure how.  Just typing sync at the terminal makes no change.  ls -la shows as 0 bytes before and after 'sync'.

Comment: `sync` does not do what you think it does. It flushes any queued write buffers out to the actual disk.

Comment: Yup, was just trying a shot in the dark.  Thanks for telling me what it actually does, I didn't really have any preconceived notions of what those were though.

Comment: I'm assuming you're connecting to the Android device over MTP?

Comment: Yes, I am using MTP.